# how can I don't get the mysql convert tuple error?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pyodbc

I just want to refresh using the UPDATE command. This gives the error, where do I make mistakes?

```
for checkNewAbility in list(newAbilities1):
    if not checkNewAbility in list(oldAbility[1]):
        my_cursor.execute(
           "UPDATE mydb.skill SET skill_name='%s' WHERE Person_person_id='%s' 
                AND skill_id='%d';",(checkNewAbility, url[0], oldAbility[0]))
        realdb.commit()
```

**Error:**

> "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing
> format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

**My Lists have:**

> oldAbility= [(43, 'PHP'), (44, 'HTML'), (45, 'CSS')]
>
> newAbilities1= ['Java', 'Python', 'JavaScript']
>
> I just want to replace oldAbilities with newAbilities1 according to id.

Comment: 2%d' missing quote?

Comment: Salmon, I wrote it wrong when I wrote here. Sorry.

Comment: still wrong %d' ?

Comment: I rewrite, but I still take this error.

Comment: You edited your question - does the error persist if you use this exact code?

Comment: Exactly, I got same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy&pasted your code correctly then there are missing double quotes " "after execute(. I assume you use pyodbc.

```
for checkNewAbility in list(newAbilities1):
    if not checkNewAbility in list(oldAbility[1]):
        my_cursor.execute("UPDATE mydb.skill SET skill_name='?' WHERE Person_person_id='?' AND skill_id='?'", (checkNewAbility, url[0], oldAbility[0]))
        realdb.commit()
```

Comment: I rewrite but same error. **mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type**

Comment: Then one of your variables you use (checkNewAbility, url[0], oldAbility[0]) has a wrong type. They should be strings or integers. You should debug your program (like printing them to console) and check the content of the variables.

Comment: I found my fault. oldAbility [1] dreamed to get programming languages. But I saw you taking them all. I wanted to get programming languages, not just numbers.